# Cursor is not updated realtime but only after event

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a drag and drop solution, but I don't want specific items to be dropped on. For that, I use the `dragnot = "true"` attribute in a div.

It works, however when an user drags a div on this `dragnot` div, I would like to change the cursor to `not-allowed`. But the cursor only updates **after** I dropped the div, not when I `dragenter`.

I have put up a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZSS4/) where it's demonstrated. Try to move div A or div C into div B. You'll see the cursor changed **after** you dropped the div (mouse over div B again if you don't see the cursor change).

How can the cursor be changed realtime?